# Let $a$ be a generator of the group of nonzero elements of $GF(p^n)$ under multiplication. Then $a$ is algebraic over $GF( p)$ of degree $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $a$ be a generator of the group of nonzero elements of $GF(p^n)$ under multiplication. Then $a$ is algebraic over $GF( p)$ of degree $n$.

The proof is given as observe that $[GF( p)(a):GF( p)] = [GF( p^n):GF( p)] = n.$

My question is, how is it that $[GF( p)(a):GF( p)] = [GF( p^n):GF( p)]$?  I see that $GF(p)(a)$ is a vector spaces over $GF(p)$ that contains $1, a,a^2, ..., a^{p-1}$, but I can't see how they're equal.

Comment: This is all because $GF(p^n)$ is the smallest field containing $a$. Is it clear to you why that is the case?

Comment: Or, what does it mean that $a$ is a generator of the group $GF(p^n)^*$? Can you say that in other words?

Comment: I understand what it means by generating the group, but I don't see how the fact that it generates a group relates to the fact that it's a vector space over a field that we're trying to find the dimension of.

Comment: Ok, good. So you know that the non-zero elements of $GF(p^n)$ are exactly the powers $1,a,a^2,a^3,\ldots,a^{p^n-2}$ with $a^{p^n-1}=1$?

Comment: Why wouldn't $a^{p^n}$ also be in that set?

Comment: It is, Oliver! But because $a^{p^n-1}=1$ (by Lagrange), then $a^{p^n}=a$, so we don't need to include it twice. You get all of $GF(p^n)$ as powers of $a$ together with $0\in GF(p^n)$.

Comment: How did you get $a^{p^n-1} = 1$?  What do you mean by "by Lagrange"?

Comment: Lagrange's theorem from elementary group theory. If a group $G$ has $m$ elements, then $a^m=1_G$. Here $G$ is the multiplicative group of the field $GF(p^n)$, so $m=p^n-1$. Because $a$ was chosen to be a primitive element (= a generator of this group), this is also the order of $a$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I forgot that the unity element $1_G$ became the identity element in the multiplicative group.  So how does this relate now?  Because it seems that $GF(p)(a)$ already contains all the $a's$?

Comment: Yes it does contain all the $a^i$s! That's the point! $GF(p^n)=GF(p)(a)$.

Comment: So because $GF(p^n)$ is cyclic and every element of $GF(p^n)$ is of the form $a^k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$, $GF(p)(a)$ contains $1, a, ..., a^{n-2}$, that implies that $GF(p)(a) = GF(p^n)$ which implies the result required?

Answer (score 1):

Consider how $F=GF(p^n)^\times$ is a group, so by LaGrange's theorem, all elements of $F$ satisfy $x^{p^n}-x=0$. Since your element generates $F$, its multiplicative order is exactly $p^{n}-1$, i.e. it does not satisfy $x^{k}-1=0$ for any $k<p^n-1$. But then if $\alpha\in E\subset F$ is in a proper subfield where here $E=GF(p^j)$ and $j<n$ then $\alpha^{p^j-1}-1=0$ a contradiction. So it must be that $\alpha$ generates the field $F$. As you have noted the degree is $n$ for that extension, so $\alpha$ must have minimal polynomial of degree $n$ as well.